# How can I call a back-end service function from the Success function of the MainCell in the front-end in a JAMstack RedwoodJS app?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, redwoodjs

I'm using [RedwoodJS](https://redwoodjs.com/cookbook/using-a-third-party-api#client-side-api-integration).

My front-end (what they call the "web" "side") has (among other files) a HomePage.ts and MainCell.ts, and then the Success function in MainCell calls a 3rd party API.

Everything is working.

However, I now want to start caching the results from the 3rd party API.

I've created a database table and a back-end "service" called cachedQueries.ts (using Prisma), which has:

```
export async function getFromCacheOrFresh(key: string, getFresh: Function, expiresInSec: number): Promise<any> {
  const nowMoment = dayjs.utc();
  const nowStr = nowMoment.format(dbTimeFormatUtc);
  const cached = await getCachedQuery({ key, expiresAtCutoff: nowStr });
  console.log('getFromCacheOrFresh cached', cached);
  if (cached) {
    const cachedValueParsed = JSON.parse(cached.value);
    console.log('cachedValueParsed', cachedValueParsed);
    return cachedValueParsed;
  } else {
    const fresh = await getFresh();
    saveToCache(key, JSON.stringify(fresh), expiresInSec);
    return fresh;
  }
}
```

I have proven that this cachedQueries.ts service works and properly saves to and retrieves from the DB. I.e. for any 3rd-party APIs that can be called from the back-end (instead of from the front-end), the flow all works well.

**Now my challenge is to enable it to cache front-end 3rd-party API queries too.**

**How I can call my `getFromCacheOrFresh` function from the Success function of the MainCell in the front-end?**

I must be confused about Apollo, GraphQL, RedwoodJS, Prisma, etc relate to each other.

P.S. Client-side caching will not suffice. I really need the 3rd-party API results to be saved in the DB on my server.

Answer (score 0):

**I eventually figured it out.**

I created a new cell called `GeoCell`, and I'm returning an empty string for each function of `GeoCell` (`Success`, `Loading`, `Empty`, and `Failure`).

That feels weird but works.

What was unintuitive to me was the idea that I was *required* to use a JSX component (since Apollo would never let me query or mutate GraphQL outside of a JSX component), but I didn’t want the cell component to actually display anything… *because* all that it needs to do in its `Success` is call a helper function that affects elements aleady created by a different cell (i.e. `addMarkerAndInfoWindow` affects the div of the existing Google Map but doesn’t display anything where the `GeoCell` was actually located).

As https://stackoverflow.com/a/65373314/470749 mentions, there's a related discussion on the [Redwood Community Forum: Thinking about patterns for services, GraphQL, Apollo, cells, etc](https://community.redwoodjs.com/t/thinking-about-patterns-for-services-graphql-apollo-cells-etc/1324/12).

Comment: The user that posted the referenced Answer is [Forrest Hayes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14856687/forrest-hayes)